# Writing to a server file from a button click in a Jekyll project

Tags: javascript, html, jekyll

As the title suggests, I do need to grab a button click from a user on a webpage, and use it to toggle a write on a file hosted on the server.

The issue is that the website is static as it is a Jekyll project, so there is no server to help do that. 
The website is static and served by an Apache server.

Any answer, even quick and dirty hacks will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a single non static file to Apache (a PHP file) to write the file. Call this PHP on button click.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into that :)